# Why anchor tag to open a section of a page goes to a blank page while using .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core

we are updating to .net core and we faced an issue

```
<a href="#list"></a>

<div id="list" />
```

this anchor tag when clicked goes to a blank page

Comment: try the following format `http://website.com/route/#tag`

Comment: In the head of your html do you have a base href set to something

Comment: How to reproduce your issue based on Asp.Net Core MVC project template? I made a test with MVC project and above code, it works and did not go to a blank page.